# Silverstripe GridField date format

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

In Silverstripe 4, in a GridField, how do we put the date in the d-m-Y format with these fields?

```
private static $summary_fields = [
    'Created',
    'LastEdited',
];

private static $field_labels = [
    'Created' => 'Criado',
    'LastEdited' => 'Logado',
];
```

Answer (score 1):

To display date in a specific format we can create a function to return the formatted date.

The following code will display the `Created` and `LastEdited` fields in the `d-m-y` format:

```
private static $summary_fields = [
    'CreatedDMY',
    'LastEditedDMY',
];

private static $field_labels = [
    'CreatedDMY' => 'Craido',
    'LastEditedDMY' => 'Logado',
];

public function getCreatedDMY() {
    return $this->dbObject('Created')->format('dd-MM-y');
}

public function getLastEditedDMY() {
    return $this->dbObject('LastEdited')->format('dd-MM-y');
}
```

If we want to display the time as well we would change the format to `dd-MM-y HH:mm:ss`

```
public function getCreatedDMY() {
    return $this->dbObject('Created')->format('dd-MM-y HH:mm:ss');
}

public function getLastEditedDMY() {
    return $this->dbObject('LastEdited')->format('dd-MM-y HH:mm:ss');
}
```

Comment: when I put this piece of code, give the following error: [Emergency] Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method CustomMemberExtension::dbObject()

Comment: If we are calling this in an extension we must add `->owner` in like this: `$this->owner->dbObject('Created')->format('dd-MM-y');`

Comment: @barbaracoltro - Happy to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer was helpful you can up vote it. If the answer solved your problem you can mark it as the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers